# Update option is not working in Shopping cart in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I created a shopping cart project in PHP but in the case of updating the quantities of cart items its not working as expected. The last Added item quantity can only update. My code to display items and update is here:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$p=$_POST['pname'];
$q=$_POST['quantity'];
        $querym =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name='$p'"); 
          while ($productByCode = mysql_fetch_array($querym)) {
                        $itemArray = array($productByCode["product_name"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode["product_name"],'p_id'=>$productByCode["p_id"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode["amount"]));
                        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            if(in_array($productByCode["product_name"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                        if($productByCode["product_name"] == $k)
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] =$q;
                    }
            } 
            else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] =    array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);

            }
             }      
            else 
            {

            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                        }
        }
                }

if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
$item_total = 0;
   ?>   
<form method="POST">        
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th><strong>Price</strong></th>
<th><strong>Total</strong></th>
<th><strong>Action</strong></th>
</tr>   
<?php 
  foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
  $total =($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);

    ?>      
            <tr>
            <td><strong><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="<?php echo     $item["p_id"];?>" class="quant" value="<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>" style="width:35;"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="pname" value="<?php echo $item["name"]; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="<?php echo $item["p_id"]; ?>">
            <p><input type="submit" value="save" name="update"></p>
                <td align=right><?php echo "$".$item["price"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$".$total; ?></td>
            <td><a href="checkout.php?act=remove&p_name=<?php echo  $item["name"]; ?>" class="btnRemoveAction">Remove Item</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
    $item_total += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
   $_SESSION['tot']=$item_total ;
    }
    ?>
  <tr>
<td colspan="5" align=right><strong>Total:</strong><?php echo  "$".$item_total; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With SQL like that please inform me of the online shop so I can avoid it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it your `$_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"]` that is not updating?

A suggestion. You should really look into preventing SQL injection, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Comment: Yes.Only last product quantity is only updating.Others no effect..Like wise button of update is only working when clicking first product quantity field.Please help me.

Comment: More data would be nice :-) Try and add 

`print '<pre>;
print_r ($_SESSION);
print '<pre>;`

just before 

`if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){`

and see how it updates when you test the cart system.